# Como chamar arquivo no HTML comprimido com gz?

Tags: javascript, html, console, importação, gzip

estou começando a usar o gzip, comprimi um arquivo JS mas quando o chamo no HTML, da erro no console.
    NO HTML

```
<script src="/presencial/includes/jorge_includes/all/js/main.js.gz/main.js"></script>
```

Na pasta está da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No console não é reconhecido as funções do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GZIP descompactar o arquivos faz parte do protocolo HTTP / 1.1 que não é usado pelos navegadores para carregar arquivos locais. Então eu acho que a resposta curta é não. Desculpa!

Você pode recorrer a arquivos descompactados ou descompactá-los antes de carregar a página da Web ou executar um daemon HTTP (servidor web) na máquina local que serve arquivos para o navegador da Web.

Referência:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding
- https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

espero que ajude

Comment: Muito  obrigado, irei procurar à respeito de como fazer, estou começando a usar o gzip agora então irei apanhar um pouco no início. Abraços!

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, aonde eu colocaria o **Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate** ?

Comment: @Jorge nos headers da requisição, no lado do cliente